# How to monitor c3p0 connections

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, health-monitoring

I am using Hibernate in my JBoss war, using c3p0 for connection pooling, both configured within a hibernate.cfg.xml config file in my classpath

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

I've seen server.log generates lines with interesting information about the connection pool:

DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@63f5e4b6 [managed: 10, unused: 9, excluded: 0]

For my monitoring pool (I am using nagios) I'd like to provide a JSP telling how many connections are being used and how many are free, as the log file says.

How can I ask c3p0 how many managed and unused connections are there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can monitor your connection pool(s) via [JMX](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#jmx_configuration_and_management). From the documentation:

> #### [Configuring and Managing c3p0 via JMX](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#jmx_configuration_and_management)
>
> If JMX libraries and a JMX
>   MBeanServer are available in your
>   environment (they are include in JDK
>   1.5 and above), you can inspect and configure your c3p0 datasources via a
>   JMX administration tool (such as
>   jconsole, bundled with jdk 1.5). You
>   will find that c3p0 registers MBeans
>   under `com.mchange.v2.c3p0`, one with
>   statistics about the library as a
>   whole (called `C3P0Registry`), and an
>   MBean for each `PooledDataSource` you
>   deploy. You can view and modify your
>   DataSource's configuration properties,
>   track the activity of Connection,
>   Statement, and Thread pools, and reset
>   pools and DataSources via the
>   `PooledDataSource` MBean. (You may
>   wish to view the API docs of
>   [`PooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html) for
>   documentation of the available
>   operations.)

By the way, there seem to be JMX plugins for Nagios, you're not forced to use a JSP.

Comment: Really, but for my approach I need this value in a variable

Comment: @LlistesSugra: Use whatever suits your needs. But in any case, JMX is the way to get the info.

Comment: the standard check_jmx nagios plugin does not work with c3p0 because the PooledDataSource has a unique string appended to its name. thats why you need the jmxquery.jar I mentioned below (it supports wildcards)

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor with Icinga/Nagios like this.

1. Download JMXQuery from google code. You will need to check out revision 18 like so.

   `svn checkout -r 18 http://jmxquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ jmxquery-read-only`
2. Download this patch. [wildcard patch for c3p0](http://jmxquery.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=120006000&name=wildcard_patch.diff&token=NSDAGokqGe8xYSU7UzjjZpRB_Cc:1375726050054)
3. use this command to patch the source code: (make sure you are in the jmxquery-read-only/src/main directory)

   `patch -p0 -i wildcard_patch.diff`
4. now download [Apache Maven](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/maven/maven-3/3.1.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.tar.gz) and extract it using this command

   `tar -zxvf apache-maven-*-bin.tar.gz`
5. now cd into the jmxquery-read-only folder and run the following command (assuming the apache maven and the jmxquery are in the same folder)

   `../apache-maven-*/bin/mvn compile`
6. then run the following command:

   `../apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn package`
7. now you should have produced a jmxquery.jar file that you can use to query the c3p0 connection pool like so: (the check_jmx file can be obtained from just downloading the jmxquery code from the google code site like normal. using [this link](http://code.google.com/p/jmxquery/downloads/detail?name=jmxquery-1.3-bin.zip&can=2&q=))

   `check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1090/jmxrmi -O com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource* -N 1 -A numBusyConnections -w 50 -c 100`

Comment: the wildcard patch for C3P0 seems to be lost, I see 0.9.5.1 has the provision to get metrics by excluding the identity token
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management

`
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true
`

Comment: The original link hostname of the `wildcard patch for c3p0` (**jmxquery.googlecode.com**) seems to be changed or move to **code.google.com/p/jmxquery** and the last version source code (1.3) cannot be downloaded.