# How to get connection pool information from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to monitor c3p0 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104125/how-to-monitor-c3p0-connections)

How can I get database connection pool information such as total connections in use, connection remaining etc ?. I want this information for logging (troubleshooting) purposes. I am using Hibernate with C3P0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104125/how-to-monitor-c3p0-connections

Answer (score 2):

We used getStatistics and getConnectCount on it, but it doesnt have any particular function to show current open connections. The getConnectCount displays the total number of connections opened

Answer (score 1):

Use `getStatistics()` method of your `SessionFactory` as per [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#getStatistics%28%29).

Comment: i tried Statistics, as you mentioned, but i am unable to get required information. Can you please pin point any particular function, which you think should work for me. Thanks