# jmxquery - null pointer exception after patching for wildcard entries

Tags: java

i want to monitor c3p0 connection pool parameters with Icinga.
So i found for this the nagios plugin jmxquery.

There will be a patch for wildcard queries.

I've patched the plugin like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065052/3536396), 
but after that i'll get NullPointerException's on every query i run.

```
[root@hostname target]# ./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<HOSTNAME>:9001/jmxrmi -O com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rw2h791t5s2b210jnofo\|2ab68416] -A numConnectionsAllUsers -I numConnectionsAllUsers -vvvv -username monitorRole -password *******************
JMX CRITICAL - NullPointerException: null connecting to com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rw2h791t5s2b210jnofo|2ab68416] by URL service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<HOSTNAME>:9001/jmxrmijava.lang.NullPointerException
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
  at jmxquery.JMXQuery.compare(JMXQuery.java:199)
  at jmxquery.JMXQuery.report(JMXQuery.java:147)
  at jmxquery.JMXQuery.main(JMXQuery.java:93)
```

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Alternate tool to access jmx beans.
Jmxterm is a command line based interactive JMX client. It's designed to allow user to access a Java MBean server from command line without graphical environment. If this is useful please check.

[JMXTerm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/manual)

Comment: Thx, i tested it, but unfortunately with this tool i'm not able to use wildcard queries.