# How to monitor connection pool issue in java in production environmant?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, c3p0, production

How to resolve the connection issues and is there any tool to monitor if available please suggest with some steps and software name

This is the error message i am getting in production environment

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
>   (maximum connections reached?): connect

Thanks

Comment: What kind of environnement do you use ? Which container, which webserver, which pooling library, which database are you connecting to ... ?

Comment: windows server,Tomcat webserver,c3p0 connection pooling,SQL server db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor c3p0 connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104125/how-to-monitor-c3p0-connections)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104125/how-to-monitor-c3p0-connections (I've also flagged your question as duplicate since google gave me this other question as 2nd link)